# What is the minimal setup requirement to make a twilio phone number callable?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am just starting to experiment with twilio and the twilio api.

I have a working account, bought a phone number that is capable of making and receiving phone calls as well as sms.

I tested making a phone call via the standard python lib. works great. Same with sending as well as receiving sms (my server as well as through the twilio console and their test web clients)

But when it comes to receiving a call from my registered Caller number, I do not get through to twilio:
The phone number seems not to be reachable at all or it hangs up immediately (not sure)

I tested with

- the TwiML bin from the twilio console as well as
- with exposed scripts (code from: https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/python/twiml/say-response) on my own server.

same effect both times.

Same when going through the web-client at
 https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/getting-started/basics :
Calling out works. Calling in not.

So I figure, I am missing some step in the registration process.

What could it be after:

1) buying the number

2) verifying caller IDs (here: my phone number) ?

Comment: Sounds like you've done the minimum to make your phone number callable. I wonder what is going on. Is there anything in the [Twilio debugger](https://www.twilio.com/console/dev-tools/debugger)?

Comment: Nothing at all. Also: no mention of incoming calls in the call log of the twilio console. The outgoing calls are logged properly.

Comment: Can you email me at philnash@twilio.com with your account SID and I'll see if there's anything I can see.

Comment: thx! you are fast! done

Comment: it works now. seems to have been a problem on operator level. thank you for your help. i will still make a ticket and note that the problem disappeared after some hours (or your call or whatever).

thanks a lot! very much appreciated!

Comment: I gotta say, it's brilliant that Twilio lurks on stackoverflow. So helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem went away after some hours without an obvious reason.
must have been a problem on another level than programming / api.